# {booktabs}: What to do with tables like these?

Tags: rules, booktabs

OK, you all know that `booktabs` forbids the use of vertical rules.

But what to do with tables like these?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
$y$ & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots & 6 \\\hline
$x$ &    &    &   &   &   &   &        &  
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

or

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
    T                                    & 2    & 5    & 10   & 25   & 50   & 100  \\[3pt] \midrule
    $x_T$                                & \multicolumn{6}{c}{{\Large known}}\\[3pt]
    $x'_T$                               &      &      &      &      &      &      \\[3pt]
    $x''_T$                              &      &      &      &      &      &      \\[3pt]
    $\displaystyle\frac{B}{\sqrt{n}}$ & \multicolumn{6}{c}{{\Large known}}\\[3pt]
    $S_T$ & & & & & &\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I feel that after T there should be a table-high vertical rule and also wonder what to do with two-row tables with lots of columns? Then again, even with two-row tables with, e.g., two columns?

Comment: this is very opinion-based and will likely get closed. But Robert Bringhurst writes in *The Elements of Typographic Style*, that rules should only go in the reading direction. Think about how the table is meant to be read. For your first example, I would get rid of all vertical lines. For the second one, I'd add some horizontal space between some of the  rows. I'd write `*{9}{c}` instead of `ccccccccc`. Use `toprule`, `midrule` and `bottomrule`.  Don't use `center` environment, use`\centering` inside a `table`.

Comment: `booktabs` does not really forbid the vertical rules but rather 'neglects' them. Vertical rules should be used for tables that are printed to serve as a fill-in-form/list only, in my point of view

Comment: Sorry, but **what are the tables for if they contain no data?!**

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

In your (second) "MWE" I make two small changes:

- instead `\midrule` I use `\hline`
- increase `\arraystretch` to 1.3

Essential part of MWE is:

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
    \begin{tabular}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}|cccccc}
T       & 2 & 5 & 10    & 25    & 50    & 100   \\
    \hline
x_T     & \multicolumn{6}{c}{{\Large known}}    \\
x'_T    &   &   &      &        &       &       \\
x''_T   &   &   &      &        &       &       \\
\frac{B}{\sqrt{n}}
        & \multicolumn{6}{c}{{\Large known}}    \\
S_T     &   &  &       &        &       &       \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: That doesn't use the booktabs package though, right?

Comment: you have right. for this table is not used.

Comment: @Jake The OP wasn't using `booktabs` either. And i think it shouldn't be used for this kind of *table*.

Comment: @Jake Agreed. Still i think that using booktabs isn't correcct here. It is an XY-problem. *How can i include graphics using package `fontenc`?* would be just the same.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can do. Note  `booktabs` isn't incompatible with mixing horizontal and vertical rules, if you set `aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` to 0pt.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon} \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{booktabs, cellspace}
 \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
 \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3!80}
\begin{tabular}{@{}Sc!{\color{LightSteelBlue3!80}\vrule width 2pt}*{6}{Sc}@{\,\,}}
 T & 2 & 5 & 10 & 25 & 50 & 100 \\ \midrule[1.2pt]
$x_T$ & \multicolumn{6}{Sc}{{\Large known}}\\
    $x'_T$ & & & & & & \\
    $x''_T$ & & & & & & \\
    $\dfrac{B}{\sqrt{n}}$ & \multicolumn{6}{c}{{\Large known}}\\
    $S_T$ & & & & & &
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}

\[ \begin{array}{c!{\color{Grey0!65!RoyalBlue3!35!}\vrule width 6pt}*{8}{c}}
y & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots & 6 \\
 x& & & & & & & &
\end{array} \]
\vspace{1cm}

\[
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\arrayrulecolor{DarkSeaGreen4!75!}
\begin{array}{!{\color{DarkSeaGreen4!75!}\vrule width 1.2pt}*{9}{c}}
y & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots & 6 \\
 x& & & & & & & & \\
  \midrule[1.2pt]
\end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]